# How to draw a fabric object with flash lines

Tags: fabricjs

I want to draw a fabric.js polygon with flash lines. What is the property that provides the flash line?

```
var points = [x0, y0, x1, y1 , x2 ,y2];
let polygon = new fabric.Polygon(points, {
    fill: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    stroke: 'red',
    selectable: false,
    objectCaching: false,
    });
```

Comment: `flash line` what do you mean by that?

Comment: I have some polygons on a fabric canvas and i have a list of object in a div. Every polygon in the canvas refers to an object in my list. I want to put a listener on my div : when i will pass the mouse over an object in my div, the border of polygon becames dashed and seems like turning about his self.